# Como Fazer o bulkcopy de um ficheiro excel para uma tabela de sql

Tags: c#, sql, microsoft-excel, sql-server

Eu queria fazer um bulkcopy de um ficheiro excel para uma tabela de sql. Mas está me a dar este erro quando tento enviar para o sql:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'O ColumnName indicado 'TransDate'
>   não tem correspondência com nenhuma coluna ma origem de dados.'

O código que eu estou a usar para fazer o bulkcopy é o seguinte :

```
string ConecçãoDB = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConecçaoDB"].ConnectionString;
            string Table = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["table"];

            string ssqltable = Table;

            string ssqlconnectionstring = ConecçãoDB;
            string sclearsql = "delete from " + ssqltable;


            var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";
            var sql = "SELECT * FROM [" + comboBox1.Text + "$]";
            MessageBox.Show(sql);
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ssqlconnectionstring);
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sclearsql, sqlconn);
            sqlconn.Open();
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlconn.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(sql);
            OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
            OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, oledbconn);
            oledbconn.Open();
            OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ssqlconnectionstring))
                {
                    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                    {

                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = ssqltable;
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(comboBox2.Text, "TransDate");
                        con.Open();
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                        con.Close();
                        try
                        {
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            // Close the SqlDataReader. The SqlBulkCopy
                            // object is automatically closed at the end
                            // of the using block.
                            MessageBox.Show("");
                        }
                    }

                }

            oledbconn.Close();
            button2.Enabled = true;
            oledbconn.Close();
        }
```

Este é o meu ficheiro excel : [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esta é a minha base de dados :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se precisarem de mais alguma coisa ou código basta pedir. Obrigado.

Comment: A mensagem indica que a coluna não existe, você verificou isso?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo a mensagem diz que não existe no excel correto ? Se sim verifiquei posso meter print do excel na questão se quiser

Comment: na verdade na relação entre comboBox2.Text e "TransDate"

Comment: @LeandroAngelo não entendi o que você quis dizer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu não entedi muito bem o motivo do seu `comboBox2.Text`. De qualquer forma, você precisa mapear as colunas da planilha com as colunas da tabela do BD, da  forma que segue abaixo.

Altere a string de conexão com o Excel colocando o parâmetro **HDR=YES**. Essa alteração é importante para que o `DataReader dr` contenha os nomes das colunas.

```
// mapear coluna da planilha Excel com a coluna da tabela do BD
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("TransDate", "TransDate");
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("TransTime", "TransTime");
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("CardNo", "CardNo");
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("VoucherNo", "VoucherNo");
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Quantity", "Quantity");
bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("TransactionValue", "TransactionValue");
```

Comment: A combo box é o que eu uso para o utilizador escolher o mapeamento que quer

Comment: Mas eu fui testar a sua maneira e dá o mesmo erro

Comment: Altere o parâmetro HDR para `HDR=YES`.